# Using arcpy to find geometry within another feature

Tags: arcpy, polygon, point, geometry, within

In Arcpy, I would like to start with a point and then using its geometry method to find out if it is inside my polygon feature (Urban Areas) deeper than the buffer distance.

This is a follow up to this post:  [Zonal Analysis using geometries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146854/arcpy-to-append-results-of-pivot-table)

```
distances=[100,200,300,400] 
for i in range(4):
    buf=point.buffer(distances[i])
    if buf.within(UrbanAreaFC):  # Error here
        arcpy.AddMessage("Inside")
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Outside")
```

The error is:  type 'exceptions.ValueError'  and the path to the geodatabase where Urban Areas is found is given.

What is that error and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm assuming you've got point from a cursor before this. What is UrbanAreaFC? It looks like a feature class, only geometries can be used in this way. Either you load all the geometries from the feature class or persist the buffer and use Select by Location with a feature count to determine overlap. If you want to find out how far they are inside get the boundary and do a near, that will tell you how far it is to the closest boundary.

Comment: It'd help if you included the full code since the error you're getting is not part of the code you provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Geometry.within()` method only accepts other `Geometry` objects -- in your case, it has to be a `Polygon`. It doesn't know what to do with a feature class, so I would suggest dissolving that feature class into one containing a single polygon, and then access the `Geometry` object with this:

```
urban_area_geom = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(DissolvedUrbanAreasFc, ['SHAPE@'])][0]
```

This returns the first (only) specified attribute -- the geometry -- for the first (only) row in the dissolved feature class.

Comment: You were right and it totally makes sense!  Thanks!